# How does the pop and isEmpty methods work in a Stack class

Tags: java

I was reading about stacks in java. I found this code . I do not understand the isEmpty method and the pop method .. I commented next to each line in the code below .. can you describe to me the pop and isEmpty methods ..
thanks

```
  public class Stack {

    int [] sk = new int[5];
    int top =-1;

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Stack s = new Stack();
    s.push(34);
    s.push(-44);
    s.push(7);

    while (!s.isEmpty())
    {
    System.out.println(s.pop());
    }
}

public int pop() {
    return sk[top--]; // what happens here? why not we use a for loop like for(int r=sk.length; r>0; r--) return sk[r];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (top==-1);      // why we return top==-1 , what is the purpose of it? should not we return sk[sk.length]==0; ?
}

public void push(int i) {
    sk[++top]=i;

}
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_stack_class.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of a Stack as sheets of paper on your desk.

With `push` you put one more sheet on top of the stack.

With `pop` you take away the topmost sheet.

With `isEmpty` you check if there are sheets left on your desk.

Sooo...

```
public int pop() {
  //Take away the element at position top and then reduce top by one
  return sk[top--]; 
}
```

More detail on isEmpty:

`top` is the *pointer* into the array of elements. Whenever this points below the lowest item (has value -1), the stack is considered empty.

`==` is the equals operator, so `(top == -1)` has a `boolean` result. It's `true` if top-pointer is pointing at -1, it's `false` otherwise.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
  //the top-most item is desk-level: No more items.  
  //Arrays in Java are 0-based, so there is no array element at -1
  return (top==-1);
}
```

Comment: why we return top==-1 , should not we return sk[sk.length]==0; ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

"pop" = pops the top item off the stack and returns it

"isEmpty" is used by the client code to know if the stack has any more items within it. (one use case is looping `while (myStack.isEmpty() == false) {}`)

---

`top--` decrements the 'top' variable after it returns the value.

`++top` increments the 'top' variable before it returns the value.

so... if you 'push' a new item onto the stack, the `top` becomes 0 (before) it returns the value which is used in placing the item into the array.

inversely from the push method is in pop where `top--` is used to decrement the value of `top` after 0 is returned by the `++` method. This makes `top` equal -1 which would mean the stack is empty. (which is it if you 'push' one item on and then 'pop' one item off

Answer (score 0):

`top` keeps track of the current index in the array `sk` (the stack pointer). Whoever wrote this code decided that when `top` = -1, this marks the stack as empty. This works with the `pop` function...

`pop` return the current item on the top of the stack (`sk[top]`) and also decrements the stack pointer (`top`).

Comment: why we return top==-1 , should not we return sk[sk.length]==0; ? thanks

Comment: No. `sk` is a fixed size array, so it's length is always 5. `-1` indicates the stack pointer is not pointing to anything.

Comment: @car You should also keep in mind that array indices start at 0. An array with a length of 3 will have indices for 0, 1, and 2 so trying to access the index at `array.length` will throw an exception every time. If you would like to access the last index use `array.length - 1`